# 'DefaultAppPool' is being automatically disabled in IIS

Tags: iis

I turned on IIS on my PC with default configuration but when I tried to access "localhost" in my browser it returned '`HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable`'.

I found that the `DefaultAppPool` under Application Pools automatically stops when it receives a request. The corresponding error under Win logs was 'Application pool `DefaultAppPool` is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool'.

I found a solution to [this issue](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/885654). However, I don't know how to use Process Monitor (which has replaced Sysinternals Regmon) to tell for which registry keys I need to provide access rights to `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`.

Could you please tell me how to use Process Monitor to identify the concerned registry keys?

Comment: Usually caused by invalid NTFS permissions on folder its trying to access. Quick solution is to create new app pool for the site, and give the new app pool identity permissions to the folder so you don't mess with the DefaultAppPool other sites could be using.